# How to access json objects in the template when HttpResponse is used in django view?

Tags: angularjs, django, django-templates

I have below code that sends id to my django view and gets couple of json objects from the server, this is working but I couldn't use the response objects in the template i.e., json objects but only one object with the context names only in my http service success function.

**Here is the view code -**

```
def preview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        response_data = {}
        try:
            data=json.loads(request.body.decode())
            v_pid=data["id"]
            basic_v_obj = tsbasicinfo.objects.get(emailid = request.session.get('emailid'))
            if tswex.objects.filter(pid = v_pid).exists():
                wc_v_obj = tswex.objects.filter(pid=v_pid)
                wc_v_qs = tswex.objects.filter(pid=v_pid)
                wc_v_json_list = [obj.as_dict() for obj in wc_v_qs]
            else:
                wc_v_obj =''
                wc_v_json_list=''
            context = {
                'js': basic_v_obj,
                'jjs':wc_v_obj,
            }
            context['wc_V_json'] = mark_safe(json.dumps(wc_v_json_list, ensure_ascii=False))
        except:
            context = {'status': "nodata"}
    return HttpResponse(context, content_type="application/json")
```

**Here is the http service function using AngularJS:**

```
        $scope.preview_ang = function (clicked_id) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'pvcan',
                data: {
                    'id': clicked_id
                },
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                })
               .success(function (data) {
                 if (data == "null") {
                     alert('server returned nothing but success');
                 } else {
                     alert(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
                     jdata = data['wc_V_json'];     
                     alert('First Sk: '+JSON.stringify(jdata)); // displays unknown.. as data is just a string object containing context names :(
                   }
               })
               .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                          alert('server returned error :'+status);
               })
        }
```

When I keep breakpoint in the view while returning HttpResponse, I can see the objects with the data that am expecting, however I am not sure how to make use of it in the javascript inside template.

When I use render_to_response method, I could use the response context as below for example -

```
jdata_wc = {{ wc_V_json|safe }};
```

How can I use the same way in my template when I return the data using HttpResponse from the view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,there are some problems with your Django code. There is no template involved, so it makes no sense to call something "context", or to use `mark_safe`. Also you only convert *some* of your variables to JSON. You need to treat the whole piece of data as one, and convert it to JSON in one go:

```
data = {
    'jobseekers': basic_v_obj,
    'jobseekers_wc': wc_v_obj,
    'wc_V_json': wc_v_json_list
}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

Then, there are issues on the client side. `JSON.stringify` is for converting JS data to JSON, not the other way round. You need `JSON.parse`.
And you are attempting to access the raw JSON data as if it were a JS object, before you convert it.

```
success(function (data) {
     if (data == "null") {
         alert('server returned nothing but success');
     } else {
         data = JSON.parse(data);
         jdata = data['wc_V_json'];     
         alert('First Sk: ' + JSON.stringify(jdata));
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel!