# How to use render_to_response to render a html page within div in Django?

Tags: angularjs, django, django-views

I have a view which returns data to template using render_to_response function as below -

```
@page_template("app/jsComp.html") # just add this decorator
def jsComp(request, template="app/jsComp.html", extra_context=None):
    basic_v_obj = js_basicinfo.objects.get(cid = request.session.get('id'))
    # Sends json data objects in context container
    .....
    context = {
    'cars': basic_v_obj,
    'companies':wc_v_obj,
    }
    context['wc_V_json'] = mark_safe(json.dumps(wc_v_json_list, ensure_ascii=False))
    return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Am able to view the context data in my template (jsComp.html) using below notation

```
  // Global variable jdata
    {% if wc_V_json %}
    jdata = {{ wc_V_json|safe }};       
    {% endif %}
    alert('Sk: '+JSON.stringify(jdata));
```

I wanted to use this template itself inside a div in another template say index.html
Also, I would like to send id from index.html via angularjs ajax call.
so, my view should consider cid equals the value that I pass via angularjs.

My question is how can I do it in index.html ?

```
$scope.preview_ang = function (clicked_id) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'pvcan',
            data: {
                'id': clicked_id
            },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            })
           .success(function (data) {
             if (data == "null") {
                 alert('server returned nothing but success');
             } else {
                 /// WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE SUCH THAT I CAN RENDER jsComp.html IN A DIV IN THE INDEX.HTML
               }
           })
           .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                      alert('server returned error :'+status);
           })
    }
```

What should I write in the success function of my angularjs ajax call to render jsComp.html in a div with some id in the index.html ?? Could you please help me with the approach ?

Am aware that I can use something like this, but this is not working (Tried calling load_page in success function but no use. How can I achieve this requirement?

```
        function load_page(){
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="previewcan" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></object>';
        }
```

Tried the below in the view but it doesn't work - (Request, Response)

```
@page_template("app/jsComp.html") # just add this decorator
def jsComp(request, template="app/jsComp.html", extra_context=None):
    data=json.loads(request.body.decode())
    v_cid=data["id"]
    basic_v_obj = js_basicinfo.objects.get(cid = v_cid)
    # Sends json data objects in context container
    .....
    context = {
    'cars': basic_v_obj,
    'companies':wc_v_obj,
    }
    context['wc_V_json'] = mark_safe(json.dumps(wc_v_json_list, ensure_ascii=False))
    return HttpResponse(context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: So you want to make a `POST` call to your Django API, get some `id` and extra data from there, and render a div with that `id`, which, in turn, contains the extra data. Did I get you right?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Django question. If you're returning data from your server which you want to insert into your page, you just do that with normal jQuery methods:

```
.success(function(data) {
    $('#info').html(data)
})
```

Comment: The problem is I cannot use json data objects to be returned via success function.. Please refer my earlier question, I tried it already  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788880/how-to-access-json-objects-in-the-template-when-httpresponse-is-used-in-django-v/34789040?noredirect=1#comment57321699_34789040

Comment: What am trying to achieve is -> send id to the view from index.html, but render the jsComp.html which gets data for that given id and get it rendered in a div in index.html....I think, this is related to Django

Comment: Well, this question is an exact duplicate of that, isn't it. Why did you ask it again?\

Comment: Did you read the questions in the first place ? I tried achieving the required but in two ways which didn't work unfortunately..  Please read them atleast before downvoting